Refactor deprecated stock registry calls when enabling MSI
I am enabling MSI on a site that has had it disabled for a long time. The site is running 2.4.6 version of Magento. We intend to have two stock sources, one source (default) will serve the main website and another source will serve the secondary website.
The site has a lot of custom logic regarding stock that relies on loading data from the now deprecated \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface::getStockItem function.
Am I correct in thinking I will have to refactor all areas in code that read stock from this deprecated function to use new interfaces defined here: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/web-api/inventory-management/? Or does MSI provide some fallback for these deprecated functions to ensure this all remains functional after enabling? The code being executed will need to correctly read stock from the source appropriate to current website, which is why I assume I need to refactor this.

Hey,  Can you once check the Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface class to het item qty data.
